# I don't understand why this Array doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My Array doesn't return, am I doing something wrong?

Here's the code:

```
console.log(rest[1]);

var rest = ["First Restaurant","Second Restaurant", "Third Restaurant"];
```

Comment: Calculate(some_number); try this

Comment: When you call the calculate function, you should give its input.

Comment: I want the numbers to be tried to an array though

Comment: I'm wondering why the array doesn't work, not the function

Comment: 1) Don't call `calcute` without an argument 2) Don't call `calcute` before you defined it 3) Don't access a property of `rest` before you defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider the order of elements, you have console.log(rest[1]) before declaring it. A function such as calculate() will be *hoisted* to the top, meaning you can safely assign it to `var price = calculate()` in the first line.

Secondly, you have:

```
var rest = ["First Restaurant", "Second Restaurant", "Third Restaurant"];
    restPrice = new Array(124, 48, 268);
```

You'll see that restPrice will not be assigned as a `var`, you're using semicolon instead of a coma:

```
var rest = ["First Restaurant", "Second Restaurant", "Third Restaurant"],
     restPrice = new Array(124, 48, 268);
```

While you get a feeling for order in variables and function hoisting, I recommend writing the file like this instead:

```
function calcute(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        return bill * 0.2;
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
        return bill * 0.15;
    } else if (bill > 200) {
        return bill * 0.1;
    }
}

var price = calcute();

var rest = ["First Restaurant", "Second Restaurant", "Third Restaurant"];
var restPrice = new Array(124, 48, 268);


console.log(rest[1]); // Outputs: "Second Restaurant"
console.log(restPrice); // Outputs: [ 124, 48, 268 ] 
var cal = calcute(restPrice[0]);
console.log('Cal: ', cal); // Outputs: Cal:  18.599999999999998
```

Note: The function is declared as `calcute`, did you mean `calculate`?